# A div taking over another div space

Tags: html, css

**The situation:** So my website is divided into sections first div inside the body is just a main container then inside of that main container there's 3 div elements first is the header second is the body or content and third is the footer.

**The problem:** On some browsers or more specifically on any browser on Iphone mobiles or ios. my footer is showing on top of the middle of the body div (content section) but on any other android phone it's looking just fine or on the normal browser..

**screenshots**:
**(normal) on any android device:-**
[screenshot on any android phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IaavQ.png)

**(problem) on any IOS device:-**
[screenshot on any ios phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sUnrB.jpg)

shared.css file that contains all the css for these pages:-
https://github.com/11abuyaman/majed/blob/master/CODE/CSS/shared.css

**link for the page that has the problem:-** 
https://11abuyaman.github.io/majed/CODE/HTML/About%20us.html

***UPDATE: 
I'm only using the flex on #clouds_body so I can be able to fit the body right in-between the header and footer and I want the footer to stuck on the bottom even if the body wasn't taking enough space.***

please help, thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide your code in the snippet?

Comment: Please provide the code... And you should read about media queries and responsive designing...

Comment: I just did provide the page link and the link of the css is already there. is that what you guys need?. thanks allot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a Safari issue, and you can solve it by removing `display: flex` on `#clouds_body`. If you're not using `flex-direction: row`, it's kind of useless to use flex on it anyways.

I also removed the flex while watching the page on Mac Firefox, and nothing changed.

**EDIT**
Based on the comment I got.

Change `height: 100%` to `min-height: 100vh` in `#clouds_body`.

This will, however, open up for other issues Safari have with your page, but that's beyond your original question.

Comment: I'm only using the flex so I can be able to fit the body right in-between the header and footer and I want the footer to stuck on the bottom even if the body wasn't taking enough space.

Comment: I updated my answer. You should update your original post with this information.

Comment: Thanks! it worked, I also changed the "height:100%;" that was on the body and html tags to "min-height:100%;".

Answer (score 0):

html code:

```
 <div id="container">
        <div id="header">header</div>
        <div id="body">body</div>
        <div id="footer">footer</div>
    </div>
```

css code:

```
#container{
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    height:auto; 
    width:auto;
}
```

This will work! This will arrange div's one below the other!

Comment: But I want to also be able to fit the body right inbetween the header and footer and I want the footer to stuck on the bottom even if the body wasn't taking enough space. :/

Comment: Then add case to the footer as bottom:some px fixed. I think this will work!